# Why are the Olympians the only truly immortal deities in The Iron Druid Chronicles?

Tags: iron-druid

In "The Iron Druid Chronicles" we are repeatedly reminded by "Atticus" that the Olympian deities (Greek/Roman) are the only truly immortal entities while all the other gods can be killed.

I can't recall a clear explanation for it through the entire series. I wonder: what is the reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the celtic mythos, the Tuatha De Dannan are mortals that have grown into god-like powers and most of the Norse gods were slated to die in Ragnarok.  The Greeks (and Romans) were conceived of originally as immortals by their worshipers and so are, as long as they are remembered at all.

Atticus is visited by Ganesh from the Indian mythos as a representative of the "omniscient" gods telling him he better fix what he broke when he started messing with the Norse pantheon.  I don't know if they are immortal as well or if they are just smarter and better connected.